# Front end editing, publishing and images tab have disappeared

Tags: articles, front-end, editor, editing

I'm using Joomla! front end editing but the only tab available is "content".

The publishing and images tabs have disappeared.  They were working so I must have changed something but I can't work out what.

I set a few of the editor-xtd plugins to "super user" so I didn't confuse authors with items that were not required.  But surely they do not control the tabs for publishing etc.

I can't think of anything else I would have changed.  I haven't done any overrides either.

Can anyone think of what I may have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by disabling mootools to try and increase the performance on the site.  Pesky mootools.

And to get the images/links tab you need to set it in the options.
[image: front end images and links]